# Sci-Fi young adult book read 1995-2001 with a not quite human boy in an egg-like space capsule on a beach

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, spaceship

Looking for a fantasy or sci fi book about a boy found in a capsule on a beach.

I do not know the title, or the author's name. I also don't know when the book came out originally. I believe the author was female, though I don't know that for certain. I believe it was written in first person with the protagonist being a teenage girl. I believe I read it sometime in the early 2000s.

It is set in a city/village where the streets are flagstone and there is mention of an artisan community and I believe one of the characters becomes an apprentice in that community. There is a beach/sea nearby and a cave/cavern somewhere along the beach. There is a scene where the girl goes swimming after dark and I remember that the water was very warm  even after the sun had set.

The main character finds a young boy in a white capsule/egg/pod on or near the beach - maybe in the water even. The boy is not quite human - though I have forgotten  how that is described/how he is different.

Over the course of the book they fall in love including a fade to black style sex scene in the cave/cavern along the beach. Near the end of the book, the boy and the girl have to explore an old crypt/labyrinth/maze I think, I'm pretty fuzzy on the details about this but the elders of the village seemed to disapprove of this.

I think the girl ended up being of a species not quite human and was more closely related to the species of person that the boy in the capsule was. The story was not set on any modern Earth, no references to actual places like London or New York. The capsule was white and smooth (I believe) and may or may not have had a long window built into its surface.

I have searched for "Pod" book and nothing quite fits - though the word pod and or capsule must have been used to describe the device that the boy was found inside. I have also tried looking up keywords for what I think the cover looked like - I think it was an egg like pod/capsule that the boy was found in on a beach scene.

I wish I knew what decade the book I'm looking for was published. All I know is that it was likely classified as a Young Adult novel at the Ransom District Library in Plainwell, MI around 1995-2005. I have also searched the Ransom District Library's website and have been checking their Young Adult section but very few books from the time period I would've read my mystery book are even still there - most books listed were only published within the last few years.

Another book I read within the same time frame was a book called "Violet Eyes" by Nicole Luiken. I mention this because it was published in 2001 and is not listed on the Ransom District Library's page, nor was I able to find a wikipedia page for it. I did however find an Amazon listing for it. All of that to say that the book I am currently looking for might be fairly obscure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Very nice first question.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you called the library itself? It may be that they have a record of your withdrawal or the librarian may recognise it if it's a book that they've regularly featured as a popular one for kids

Comment: https://www.pinereadsreview.com/blog/the-way-we-love-here-from-meet-cute-dhonielle-clayton/ - *The Way We Love Here* seems to contain a lot of the same tropes; boy on beach, etc

Comment: Did check with the library. Those records have been purged apparently and the staff was not able to help. Thanks for looking for me but that story is published much too recently.

Comment: Not-quite-human male found in an egg-shaped capsule? Sounds like Mork of _Mork and Mindy_ fame. He was boy-like (since he didn't know anything about Earth), but he wasn't found on a beach, and I don't know if there was ever a book form of the TV show...

Comment: "most books listed were only published within the last few years" - aren't libraries supposed to be repositories of knowledge and information, both new _and_ old? This is sad...

Comment: @FreeMan They get their funding based on circulation numbers, so they need to replaced "frivolous" fiction content and keep it up to date -- limited space means the replaced volumes are sold off (many/most libraries have annual book sales).